# How to reproduce specific Friendly URL?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, friendly-url, prettyfaces

we are trying to refactor an JSP/XSLT application to JSF. We use a CMS for content management. Technologies : JSF 2.0 using Mojarra, PrimeFaces 2.2.1 and Tomcat 6.29
The organisation of the data structure is the following:
There are Sites.
Sites contain Channels.
Channels contain Contents.
Sites, channels and content are translated.

The URLs look like:
`http://whatever/firstSite`
`http://whatever/firstSite/aChannel`
`http://whatever/firstSite/aChannel/aSubChannel/myGreatContent`

It's the translated name who is showing to the user. The siteName only appears once, channel can appear many times and the content at maximum once

For the moment, we use commandLinks.
The action call update the context of the application and return the page id.

Now we want to reproduce the friendly URL and replace the commandlink navigation (POST) with h:link or outpulink (GET).

I read some stuffs about FURL with JSF and I saw the PrettyFaces's solution.

Can i reproduce the FURL with prettyfaces or should i implemented by mysefl (like explains in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/friendly-urls-in-jsf.html)) ?

And with h:link, i don't see actionListener or action attribute, so how i can update my context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cross posted on: http://ocpsoft.com/support/topic/how-to-reproduce-specific-friendly-url (Please follow up there.)

Comment: can you please take a look at my issue with prettyfaces latest version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771716/primefaces-fileupload-is-not-working-with-prettyfaces-and-spring-boot/44804768#comment76596510_44804768

Answer (score 2):

> *Can i reproduce the FURL with prettyfaces or should i implemented by mysefl (like explains in this article)?*

I would definitely recommend [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/). You end up with less complicated code and configuration. The same is also mentioned in the top of the linked article.

> *And with h:link, i don't see actionListener or action attribute, so how i can update my context?*

The `<h:link>` only accepts a navigation outcome, not an URL. Use `<h:outputLink>` instead.

```
<h:outputLink value="firstSite/aChannel/aSubChannel">A sub channel</h:outputLink>
```

As to invoking actions on GET requests, use the constructor or `@PostConstruct` of the bean which is associated with the view.

Comment: For the h:link i think to use outcome like channel and use f:param to pass the id of the target channel, like you present in your article. But for PrettyFaces, I don't know how to start, do you have some advices, hints or resources for my situation?