# Are there any ways to access back-end bean's method based on the specific URL in a JSF + PrimeFaces Project?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to access back-end bean's method without using any menu or link. For example, if I type `http://localhost:8080/myproject/userObj/userNew`, `userNew` method will be called. If I type `http://localhost:8080/myproject/userObj/userList`, `userList` method will be called. Are there any ways to setup like above?

At my current project, I use PrimeFaces Menubar. Attribute `action` is used to point to the bean's method. What I want is some mapping feature that will access bean's method based on the URL. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reproduce specific Friendly URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174487/how-to-reproduce-specific-friendly-url)

Comment: Maybe some jsf annotation above the method will map with the specific URL? Actually I don't need the pretty URL. When there's no other solution, I'm gonna try prettyfaces. Thanks! :-)