# Primefaces FileUpload is not working with PrettyFaces and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2, prettyfaces

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE with JSF 2.2.14 and Primefaces 6.1 and PrettyFaces 3.4.1.Final.

My pom file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>140</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jcr/jcr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr2dav -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr2dav</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-rmi</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <configuration> <source>1.6</source> <target>1.6</target> </configuration> 
                </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                  <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

my springboot configuration class is as follows:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.Collections;

import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;

import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;

@SpringBootApplication
@URLMappings(mappings = { @URLMapping(id = "login", pattern = "/login", viewId = "/faces/public/login.xhtml")})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextCustomizer() {
        return new ServletContextInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
                servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
                servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
                servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
                servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
                servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.setScopes(Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap(FacesViewScope.NAME, new FacesViewScope()));
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean FileUploadFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
        registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        registration.addServletRegistrationBeans(servletRegistrationBean());
        registration.setOrder(2);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterDisabled(
            @Qualifier("hiddenHttpMethodFilter") HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

}
```

the xhtml page for upload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="/template/commonLayout.xhtml">   

            <ui:define name="content">              
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <p:commandButton value="test" action="#{testBean.test}"/>
                   <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{testBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                  multiple="true"  update="messages" />
                  <h:messages id="messages"></h:messages>
                </h:form>           
            </ui:define>



        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

the fileupload backing bean is as follows:

```
package com.myapp.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("testBean")
@Scope("view")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3568561158943789169L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestBean.class);

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        log.info("####### handleFileUpload,file: " + event.getFile().getFileName());
    }   

}
```

I am running on `tomcat 9.0.0.M21` and when choosing the file and clicking upload I get no client side errors and no server side errors and the file is not getting uploaded, although when I turned on primefaces debugging it prints that the file was uploaded:

```
2017-06-27 07:32:04,926 DEBUG o.p.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter - Parsing file upload request
2017-06-27 07:32:04,969 DEBUG o.p.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter - File upload request parsed succesfully, continuing with filter chain with a wrapped multipart request
```

but the code in the listener in the backing bean was not invoked.

**It seems that the issue is because of prettyfaces, when I remove it from the project, the filter works fine.**

I also tried the context.xml solution for the prettyfaces issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
</Context>
```

and the problem is not solved.

Comment: I had problems with this some time ago. I couldn't configure it to work with the provided tomcat way (servlet 3.0), so I ended up configuring it with [the apache commons uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588153/1199132). You still have the extra matter of having the rewrite filter. I think your best chance is to set up a Spring Boot project from scratch and try to make it work (without rewrite). Then you can port it to your project once you get it.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, i saw your post, and i think that my configuration is similar to yours, but maybe as you are saying some extra library in my side is conflicting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i figured it out, there are two solutions:

1- Make the **DispatcherType** for **primefaces** upload filter **FORWARD** ONLY

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean FileUploadFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
        registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterDisabled(
            @Qualifier("hiddenHttpMethodFilter") HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

2- If you want the primefaces upload filter dispatcher type to be FORWARD and REQUEST you have to explicitly define the pretty faces rewrite filter:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean prettyFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean prettyFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new RewriteFilter());
        return prettyFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean FileUploadFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter());
        registration.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterDisabled(
            @Qualifier("hiddenHttpMethodFilter") HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I don't understand why.  Or what changed between primefaces 6.0 and 6.1.  I was also able to upgrade a separate project from 6.0 to 6.2 without needing to do this.  Can you provide any documents explaining the change?

Answer (score 4):

I might be late on this one but i know it will save someone some time, i had a similar problem with file upload recently using primefaces6.1 and springboot. My solution was to explicitly set the **MultipartConfigElement within the ServletRegistrationBean**.
The compete working configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class JsfConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD", "0");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("facelets.DEVELOPMENT", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "bootstrap");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServlet() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
        registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new
                MultipartConfigElement((String) null));
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean facesUploadFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new FileUploadFilter(), facesServlet());
        registrationBean.setName("PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter");
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("Faces Servlet");
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer(){
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        Map<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        scopes.put("view", new ViewScope());
        configurer.setScopes(scopes);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement((String) null)); was the line I was missing. Works for me now

Answer (score 0):

In regardless of Spring Boot, I had this problem before between PrettyFaces and PrimeFaces, it can be solved by configuring the right filters mapping in `web.xml` as the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>     

<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm not sure if this answer would be helpful in your Spring Boot environment, as I don't have a lot of experience in that stack.

Comment: the filters are already configured similar to what you posted

Comment: I see, in my case it was the dispatcher Forward the Faces Servlet that solved my problem.